# TCAM entry width

Tags: ipv4, ipv6

if IPv4 is 32 bits and IPv6 is 128 bits wide, why TCAM is configured to be 36, 72, or 144 bits wide? why don't configure it as 32, 64, and 128 bits?

if there is link for reading material would be better.

Comment: so, how does it relate to TCAM width? I mean even 32, 64, and 128 bits can also do the job right? or if overflow happened, is it going to fill the next available entries on the TCAM? lets say that for 1 ACL entry, will it require two TCAM entries? sorry, I still did not understand the relation between TCAM width and TCAM table update mechanism

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***TCAM*** table is designed to make the process of lookup for IPs involved in layer 3 function such ***(routing,ACL,QOS,filtering)*** more easier but return not only 0 in case of match and 1 in case of no match but also X in case of don’t care which mean ***(For example, a ternary CAM might have a stored word of "10XX0" which will match any of the four search words "10000", "10010", "10100", or "10110" (XX can be 00,01,10,11).)*** and also add little bits to the table entry width

you can say a multi layer switch uses sets of TCAMs, each set of TCAMs are used for a certain feature ***(Routing, QoS, ACLs ...)***, and it does parallel lookups to get all the required results using the VMR combination ***(Value, Mask and Result)***, these results can be permit and deny in the case of ACLs, values for QoS policies in case of QoS or pointers to a next-hop in the routing table in case of routing

***NOTE***
you have conflict when you consider the TCAM entry width is directly related to the length of the IP address cause each entry is consented of 3 parts(Value (134 bit), Mask (134 bit), result (permit,deny)) and those three pars are varying from layer 3 function to another layer 3 function as shown in the next table .

[image]

*entry width note depend only on the width of IPs but also on the lookup mechanism used to find specific entry and the compression mechanism used to compress those information in one table entry ,*

an examble for TCAM entry produced by multi access list entries

[image]

also this [this link](https://supportforums.cisco.com/sites/default/files/legacy/5/5/1/10155-TCAM.pdf) could be useful to understand the TCAM table complete process . and this [google book](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=AFeNDyyiNCIC&pg=PA86&lpg=PA86&dq=tcam%20table%20entry%20width&source=bl&ots=USEG91UC3w&sig=1zYsm6AwMoH7XSj_O3msHI1lmtk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDMQ6AEwA2oVChMIqZSZ77yOyQIVy1UaCh3R0A9O#v=onepage&q=tcam%20table%20entry%20width&f=false) speak about the lookup mechanisms used in TCAM table build

Comment: If you quote other sources or use their diagrams, please give a reference

Comment: I'm assuming you didn't draw your diagram and tables.  Please provide a link or reference to the source.